# Why the color string gives different result if produced by python?

Tags: terminal, python, colors, escape-characters

I ran followings commands in git-bash terminal on Windows 10:

```
~$ printf $'\x1b[30;42mHello, World!\x1b[0m\n'                                                      
Hello, World! # correct color shown
~$ python -c "import sys;print(sys.argv[1])" $'\x1b[30;42mHello, World!\x1b[0m\n'
<-[30;42mHello, World!<-[0m  # just escape sequence

~$
```

'<-' is a single character for Escape.

Comment: works for me on Debian

Comment: @ilkkachu, thanks. It seems to be related to git-bash terminal on Windows 10.